# Sonar-runner on remote machine not picking up correct jbdc connection?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have sonarqube 3.5.1, and sonar-runner 2.2.1 on a RHEL6.2 server, sonar-runner works fine against the sample data I've downloaded.

However, I've deployed sonar-runner to a windows client, and its failing to connect to the H2 database.

```
INFO: Sonar Server 3.5.1
11:58:19.960 INFO  - Load batch settings
11:58:20.116 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\e01942082\.sonar\cache
11:58:20.132 INFO  - Install plugins
11:58:21.739 INFO  - -------------  Executing Project Scan
11:58:22.113 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
11:58:22.129 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
11:58:22.129 WARN  - H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
11:58:22.129 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 8.393s
Final Memory: 2M/15M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Fail to connect to database
ERROR: Caused by: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost" [90067-167])
ERROR: Caused by: Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost" [90067-167]
ERROR: Caused by: Connection refused: connect
```

So, I've updated the sonar-properties in sonarqube

```
# Comment the following line to deactivate the default embedded database.
sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:h2:tcp://gbrpsr000000711.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.com:9092/sonar
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                org.h2.Driver
```

and sonar-runner conencts to the server with the

```
sonar.host.url=http://gbrpsr000000711.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com:9000/sonar
```

its not clear why its picking up the localhost rather than the full url of the server. Am I missing somehting/ or has this been embedded when I started the service prior to making the config changes????

thanks for you assistance

dD

Comment: I think that you can't connect to the embedded database from another machine. Why don't you try to use a more stable db, like postgress or mysql?

Comment: I'm in the process of setting my mysql, still, for a quick eval/deploy I wasn't expecting to have to configure an external database as well. Will see how we get on with mysql

Comment: mysql installed, and configured, working a treat now